# measure MSE between two columns in pySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I am new in pySpark and have some problem with handling the data.

I have a dataFrame with two columns and no header in pySpark (2.1.0).
I want to calculate the MSE (RegressionMetrics.MeanSquaredError) between the first and the second column:

```
df = sc.textFile("data.csv").map(lambda l: l.split(","))
df1 = df.map(lambda x: map(eval, x))
df2 = df1.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row[0], row[1]))
baseline_mse_measure = RegressionMetrics(data_mse_df)
print("Baseline MSE = %s" % baseline_mse_measure.meanSquaredError)
```

But get an error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o6652.meanSquaredError.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 905.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 905.0 (TID 4858, mapr-10089-prod-nydc1.nydc1.outbrain.com, executor 138): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main
    process()
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 169, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<ipython-input-148-177a4d3966f7>", line 6, in <lambda>
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/python/pyspark/mllib/regression.py", line 54, in __init__
    self.features = _convert_to_vector(features)
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/python/pyspark/mllib/linalg/__init__.py", line 80, in _convert_to_vector
    raise TypeError("Cannot convert type %s into Vector" % type(l))
TypeError: Cannot convert type <type 'float'> into Vector

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1436)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1424)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1651)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1606)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1595)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1981)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$aggregate$1.apply(RDD.scala:1115)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.aggregate(RDD.scala:1108)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics.summary$lzycompute(RegressionMetrics.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics.summary(RegressionMetrics.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics.SSerr$lzycompute(RegressionMetrics.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics.SSerr(RegressionMetrics.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics.meanSquaredError(RegressionMetrics.scala:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main
    process()
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 169, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<ipython-input-148-177a4d3966f7>", line 6, in <lambda>
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/python/pyspark/mllib/regression.py", line 54, in __init__
    self.features = _convert_to_vector(features)
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/python/pyspark/mllib/linalg/__init__.py", line 80, in _convert_to_vector
    raise TypeError("Cannot convert type %s into Vector" % type(l))
TypeError: Cannot convert type <type 'float'> into Vector

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Any ideas why? And what fix should I do to calculate the MSE between the two columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `LabeledPoint`. Instead:

```
df2 = df1.map(lambda row: (row[0], row[1]))
baseline_mse_measure = RegressionMetrics(data_mse_df)
```

Comment: I get the error: TypeError: DoubleType can not accept object 1348713 in type <type 'int'>
in the MSE calculation, what may cause it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegressionMetrics` to implement:

```
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import RegressionMetrics

predictions = model.transform(test_df)

valuesAndPreds = predictions.select(['the_label_col', 'prediction_col'])
# It needs to convert to RDD as the parameter of RegressionMetrics
valuesAndPreds = valuesAndPreds.rdd.map(tuple)


metrics = RegressionMetrics(valuesAndPreds)

# Squared Error
print("MSE = %s" % metrics.meanSquaredError)
print("RMSE = %s" % metrics.rootMeanSquaredError)

# Mean absolute error
print("MAE = %s" % metrics.meanAbsoluteError)
```

Reference:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html
http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=regressionmetrics#pyspark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics